# Weird behavior of RewriteOptions Inherit, InheritDown, InheritBefore, etc when adding www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to have a child `.htaccess` with `RewriteEngine on` that inherits parent directory's `RewriteRule`s.

#### OK (only parent `.htaccess` with `RewriteEngine on`)

Condition:

```
# /.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# /article/.htaccess
(Empty or without RewriteEngine on)
```

Result:

```
example.com/article/34 => www.example.com/article/34
```

### Parent rule ignored (at least in some cases)

Condition:

```
# /.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions InheritDown #or InheritDownBefore
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# /article/.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
```

Result:

```
example.com/article/34 => example.com/article/34
```

### Parent rule becomes wierd

Condition:

```
# /.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# /article/.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions Inherit #or InheritBefore
```

Result:

```
example.com/article/34 => www.example.com/34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest not to use `Inherit` or similar options at all and instead, try to have as few `.htaccess` files with `RewriteEngine on` as possible.

If you needed to have a `RewriteEngine on` in a child `.htaccess` file, you can re-write desired rules in it yourself:

```
# /article/.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/article/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

(Note the added `article/` at last line)